# jquery mobile photoswipe on rubyonrails website

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery-mobile

I am setting up a photoswipe with jquery mobile on the rubyonrails server, for some reason, the photoswipe only start after refresh the page, but when I put the script of the page to normal website, it will working fine.

Anyone can tell me what way I can make it work withouth refreshing please:

site add: http://prod.computersforpeople.info/users/262/properties/47198

when you click on the photo, it will link to the photoswipe page, but it won't start until you refresh the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when it only works after a reload of the mobile page, i assume that you are using the dom-ready event to register the photoswipe.

since jquery mobile loads pages via ajax, you need to bind to pageinit events. see the docs for further details: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/api/events.html

Comment: can you tell more details for how to bind to pageinit events? still no idea what to do after read the link you provide